# Javascript: this and onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a simple slideshhow with 4 images and on click, it makes it appear in the larger div box.  Pretty self explanatory, but feel free to ask me any questions.  Since the slideshow only has 4 images, I would leave the code as is.  But what if I had 100+ pictures?  I think copying and pasting my javascript function for each onclick event would not be as clean as another solution.  My question is how would I make the javascript so that whenever I click on a image, it gets that image in the box and puts it in the big container and just make my code cleaner in general.  Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/p3Lg96p8/

```js
function clickFunction(){
  document.getElementById("big").style.backgroundImage="url('http://assets22.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/007.png')";
  
}

function clickFunction2(){
  document.getElementById("big").style.backgroundImage="url('http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/f/fb/143Snorlax.png/250px-143Snorlax.png')";
  
}
function clickFunction3(){
  document.getElementById("big").style.backgroundImage="url('http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140410200831/pokemon/images/0/02/025Pikachu_Dream.png')";
  
}
function clickFunction4(){
  document.getElementById("big").style.backgroundImage="url('http://pre03.deviantart.net/27f2/th/pre/f/2012/218/0/7/_004_charmander___1st_attempt_sugimori_style_by_white__flame-d59zqwh.png')";
  
}
```

```css
#container{
 border:solid 2px;
 width:1100px;
 height:600px;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
}

#big{
 
 border:solid 2px;
 border-color:blue;
 height:350px;
 background:gray;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
}

.slides{
 text-align:center;
margin-top:30px;
border: solid 2px red;
height:200px;

}

.thumb{

 border:solid 2px green;
 width:260px;
 height:100%;
 margin:0px;
 display:inline-block;

}

.thumb img{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}



.thumb:hover{

 border:solid 4px red;

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>MySlide</title>

<body>

 <div id="container">
  Container
     <div id="big">
      big
     </div>

     <div class="slides">

      <div class="thumb one" onclick="clickFunction()">
       <img src="http://assets22.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/007.png">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb 2"onclick="clickFunction2()">
      <img src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/f/fb/143Snorlax.png/250px-143Snorlax.png">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb 3"onclick="clickFunction3()">
      <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140410200831/pokemon/images/0/02/025Pikachu_Dream.png">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb 4"onclick="clickFunction4()">
      <img src="http://pre03.deviantart.net/27f2/th/pre/f/2012/218/0/7/_004_charmander___1st_attempt_sugimori_style_by_white__flame-d59zqwh.png">
      </div>





     </div>


          </body>
```

Comment: I would create an array of objects that have all the slide show picture URLs, with their associated larger pics, that when you click, will do a lookup. That way you could build a slideshow of infinite length by looping over this array, and building an element and registering a click handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a more elegant way of doing it with an array of urls:

```
var urls = [
    "http://assets22.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/007.png",
    "http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/f/fb/143Snorlax.png/250px-143Snorlax.png",
    "http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140410200831/pokemon/images/0/02/025Pikachu_Dream.png",
    "http://pre03.deviantart.net/27f2/th/pre/f/2012/218/0/7/_004_charmander___1st_attempt_sugimori_style_by_white__flame-d59zqwh.png"
];

function clickFunction(num) {
    document.getElementById("big").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + urls[num] + "')";
}
```

Then you can use `clickFunction(0)`, `clickFunction(1)`, `clickFunction(2)`, etc. for your div `onclick`s.

Alternatively you could automate that part as well:

```
var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName("thumb");
for (var i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
    thumbs[i].onclick = (function(index){
        return function() {
            document.getElementById("big").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + urls[index] + "')"
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, a lot cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add the url as a parameter to the onclick function:

```
function clickFunction(url) {
  document.getElementById("big").style.backgroundImage="url('"+ url + "')";
}
```

Then pass that in your html

```
  <div class="thumb one" onclick="clickFunction(http://assets22.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/007.png)">
    <img src="http://assets22.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/007.png">
  </div>
```

Comment: This could work too but I think I like having all my url links in the javascript better since they like to clutter up my HTML markup.  Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/darxide/p3Lg96p8/1/

That code gets the source directly from clicked image and displays it as a background of #big container

```
$('img').click(function() {

var a = $(this).prop('src')

$('#big').css({
    backgroundImage : 'url("'+a+'")'
})

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all of your functions are essentially identical, just with different URLs, you should use a parameter. You could either pass in the URLs, or you could keep all of the URLs in an array and then pass in an integer that would identify the correct one.